# Python split behavior with Unicode regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, unicode

Running Python 2.7.12.

I'm encountering some unexpected behavior using `split` with Unicode regular expressions, more specifically involving `\w` and `\W`. (I've checked other questions and know to include the `re.UNICODE` flag and to write strings as `u'whatever'`.)

For simplicity, we can boil the issue down to working with a single character, let's say я (i.e. `\u044f` in Python).

On the one hand, I get

```
>>> re.match(ur'\w', u'\u044f', re.UNICODE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb70e7528>
```

which is what I would expect: я matches with `\w`.

On the other hand,

```
>>> re.split(ur'\w', u'\u044f', re.UNICODE)
[u'\u044f']
```

whereas, based on the previous match, I would expect the output here to be `[u'', u'']`.

This can be flipped around with `\W` as follows:

```
>>> re.match(ur'\W', u'\u044f', re.UNICODE)
>>> re.split(ur'\W', u'\u044f', re.UNICODE)
[u'', u'']
```

Again `re.match` is what I would expect (no match), but then `re.split` seems to do an about face, acting as like there is a match.

What's going on here?

Comment: try specifying the named argument `flags` with `re.split(ur'\w', u'\u044f', flags=re.UNICODE)`

Comment: @ruaridhw Thanks, that took care of it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter to `re.split` is `maxsplit` not `flags`:

```
>>> import re
>>> help(re.split)
Help on function split in module re:

split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0, flags=0)
    Split the source string by the occurrences of the pattern,
    returning a list containing the resulting substrings.  If
    capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all
    groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting
    list.  If maxsplit is nonzero, at most maxsplit splits occur,
    and the remainder of the string is returned as the final element
    of the list.
```

So use either:

```
re.split(ur'\w', u'\u044f', 0, re.UNICODE)
```

or:

```
re.split(ur'\w', u'\u044f', flags=re.UNICODE)
```